# Overload + Operator for Class Data

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Assume that I have the following basic class where I want to overload operator+:

```
class foo {
private:
    arbitrary datatype

public:
    foo() { set private data; };
    virtual ~foo() {};

};
```

I've always used this format:

```
foo operator+( const foo &rhs );
```

However, I've recently stumbled onto some code where the person exclusively used:

```
friend foo operator+( const foo &lhs, const foo &rhs );
```

So, is it standard to use one version over the other?  Are there situations where you would be forced into one version (This is only for adding the same object types)?  I'm not familiar with assembly language, but would the compiler convert these into the same list of instructions (This question is obviously dependent on answers to the first 2)?

Comment: The one-argument version is for when the operator is a *member* function, the two-argument version is a stand-alone (non-member) function. Some operators can only be implemented using member-functions, but for the others it's up to you as a designer and implementer to decide what you prefer. Also remember that member functions can of course access private data, while non-friend non-member function can't.

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6255825/560648

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **To answer your first 2 questions**

   It is recommended (but not enforced) to use the `friend` approach for binary operators because it allows to have objects that are convertible to your class on the left hand side of the operator. Consider this:

   ```
   class Foo
   {
       // private members
   public:
       Foo(int) {/* ctor implementation */} // implicit convertible to int
       Foo(const Foo&) { /* copy ctor implementation */ }
       friend Foo operator+(const Foo& lhs, const Foo& rhs){/* implementation */}
   };
   ```

   Now you can do:

   ```
   Foo foo1{1};
   Foo foo2 = 1 + foo1; // 1 is implicitly converted to Foo here
   ```

   If `operator+` would have been a member function, the call above would fail (left hand side, even if convertible to `Foo`, will not be automatically converted by the compiler), and you'd be only able to use

   ```
   Foo foo2 = foo1 + 1;
   ```

   So, in conclusion, using `friend` for binary operators make them more "symmetric".
2. **Last question:**

   The assembler would not generate the same code, as the friend/member `operator+` are doing slightly different things.

See also a **very** good guide about overloading operators [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading).

Comment: Ah, cool, I didn't realize that.  So, to understand what's going on, is the '1' in `Foo foo2 = 1 + foo1` automatically tossed into a constructor?  That looks like what happened in my program where I'm applying this.

Comment: Yes, `foo2` is copy constructed from the result of `operator+(Foo{1}, foo1)`

Comment: @TriHard8 and yes, `1` on the lhs is automatically casted into `Foo{1}` then passed to `operator+`